# Event is not working in React Hooks while passing an id . TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, events, dom-events

Event is not working in React Hooks while passing an id. I want to get the id in that function but have some TypeError:

```
{item.is_favorite ? <FavoriteIcon className={classes.fav} /> : <FavoriteBorderIcon className={classes.remFav} onClick={() => addFav(item.id)} />}

  let addFav = (event, id) => {
     event.stopPropagation();
    alert(id);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

The first argument is event object and the second one is your item's id.

```
{item.is_favorite ? <FavoriteIcon className={classes.fav} /> : <FavoriteBorderIcon className={classes.remFav} onClick={(e) => addFav(e, item.id)} />}
```